# Jquery Drag and Drop with text in div into smaller div

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui, laravel

First, I use Laravel 4, and some plugins like Bootstrap, jQuery, jQuery-ui...

I have a problem with jQuery UI draggable/Droppable.

I have a table full of divs, with a size that I don't want to change. It's a horizontal calendar with days at left, hours at top. When I drag and drop a little "div" with only "event" as text, it's ok. But when I have a text like "VERY BIG TITLE FOR EVENT", the div is 'splitted' in many part (see jsFiddle below). I wanted to be able to resize the event. For example, if the event need to be "ON" at 8:00am until 4:00pm, the draggable event can be dropped at the "8:00" column, and can be resized to "4:00pm"... But with that "split" problem, I will not be able to do that.

```
for (var j = 0; j < 24; j++){
    $("#creneau"+i).append("<div class='creneau' id='creneau"+i+"-"+j+"' style='display: inline-block; float: left; margin 0; width: 40px; height: 20px; '></div>");
    $("#creneau"+i+"-"+j).droppable({
        appendTo: "body",
        tolerance: "pointer",
        accept: ".external-event",
        drop: function(event, ui) {        
            $(this).append($(ui.draggable));
        }
    });
}

$(".external-event").draggable({
    appendTo: "#hours-creneau",
    cursor: "move",
    helper: 'clone',
    revert: "invalid"
});
```

Here, the jsFiddle link for ALL the code (little big). [Link to jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n3Smt/)

My tab is really "large" on jsFiddle, sorry about that. You maybe will need to resize...

Comment: Just a tip, remove `"See this fiddle for an example` from the link to JsFiddle

Comment: Yeah, thanks to AnoopJoshi who edited and removed that mistake. Thanks for the tip @urbz :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's just a styling-problem.
To avoid the 'split', as you call it, just add the style

```
white-space: nowrap;
```

to the event-element. Then it wont get split.

Comment: Thanks. Adding white-space on the "droppable" div, not on the event "draggable" div, solved the problem. Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you want correctly, this seems to just be a css issue to fix the splitting of the text. Your span tag's width is contained so you either need to move the text to a seperate span inside and or use some styling on your width.

The following may get you on the right track.

Try giving it a specified width (size of your cell - 40px minus box model - 28px

```
.external-event {
    display:inline-block;
    width:28px;
}
```

You could then use your javascript to change the width when you span/drag the event over multiple hours.

You may want to cut off the extra text and display it on hover/tooltip etc

```
.external-event {
        overflow:hidden;
    }
http://jsfiddle.net/n3Smt/6/
```

In order for the text to display in full without affecting the shape of your event, put it in a seperate span inside and then add some styling to the innner span for example:

```
<span class='external-event'><span class=textWrapper>BIG EVENT WITH SPACES</span></span>

.textWrapper {position:absolute;}
```

Comment: The result is not what I expected. Btw, @Homungus answered good, so I will use his method. Thanks for trying. :-)